# My app just crashed, how can I get the crash log?

Tags: java, android, logging, crash

I am testing my app on my actual device, and it seems like there is a memory leak. The app has crashed after a couple of hours. How can I pull up the log of the crash?

I plugged my phone in via USB and tried:

```
adb logcat -v
```

but I get the following message in my terminal:

```
- waiting for device -
error: more than one device and emulator
```

How can I diagnose my crash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because there's...

> > more than one device and emulator

The error is fairly clear. So, what you do in this case is:

```
adb devices
```

And it lists the name of your devices/emulators. Then:

```
adb -s name-of-your-device logcat
```